# Request returned undefined method `parse' when extend Sensu Plugin Metric class

Tags: ruby, sensu

I am calling an API in [Sensu custom metric-collection-check](https://docs.sensu.io/sensu-core/1.5/guides/intro-to-checks/#create-a-metric-collection-check), but when I tried to parse the response its throw the below error

```
Request returned undefined method `parse' for Sensu::Plugin::Metric::CLI::JSON:Class
```

While the same API parse working in [standard-check](https://docs.sensu.io/sensu-core/1.5/guides/intro-to-checks/#create-a-standard-check)  when it extends from `Sensu::Plugin::Check`

Here is the check

```
    #!/opt/sensu/embedded/bin/ruby
    require 'socket'
    require 'active_support/core_ext/hash'
    require 'json'
    require "rest-client"
    require 'sensu-plugin/metric/cli'

    class SomeName < Sensu::Plugin::Metric::CLI::Graphite
    option :scheme,
            description: 'Metric naming scheme, text to prepend to metric',
            short: '-s SCHEME',
            long: '--scheme SCHEME',
            default: "#{Socket.gethostname}.stream"

    def run
        response = ""
        begin
        response =::JSON.parse RestClient::Request.execute(method: :get, url: "http://localhost:3001/stats" )
        rescue Exception => e
        critical "#{config[:scheme]}.name Metric check failed, Request returned #{e.message}"
        end
        output "#{config[:scheme]}.somekey", response["somekey"]
        ok
    end
    end
```

Working with the following class.

```
class SomeName < Sensu::Plugin::Check::CLI
```

Seems like something wrong with sense metric plugin, any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the issue by calling global method using `::` Operators also it does not require to import `require 'json'` as sensu-plugin come with JSON class.

> For a metric, you can subclass one of the following:

`Sensu::Plugin::Metric::CLI::JSON`

[sensu-plugin Checks and Metrics](https://github.com/sensu-plugins/sensu-plugin)

```
response =::JSON.parse RestClient::Request.execute(method: :get, url: "http://localhost:3001/stats" )
```